# Verifying Cognito access tokens server-side

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-go

I've got a Cognito access token server-side using `AdminInitiateAuth` (AWS SDK for Go) and I'm storing that in a session cookie. I'm assuming I need to validate that token on every subsequent request. Do I need to call out to Cognito for every request, or can I validate the token in my app server-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**OpenID is a decentralized authentication protocol**" So you don't have to query a DB server or the Cognito server to verify it because of the asymmetric **RSA** approach.

I had the same issue with OpenID tokens. I'm using Cognito to register to sign-In and sign-up my users. initially, I could authorize them by using an API gateway authenticator without issues but later I decided to move this in a Kubernetes backend.

The best idea I found around is from:
[How to verify a JWT Token from AWS Cognito in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905995/how-to-verify-a-jwt-token-from-aws-cognito-in-go) thread

and a good Python example from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/blob/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt/decode-verify-jwt.py

> you'll need the public key in order to verify the JWT token

JWT tokens have a based64 URL encoded JSON format with three fields `<header>.<payload>.<signature>`.
In the payload field you can find the `iss` field to search the the **"kid" public key** before trying to do the verification.

```
testparse := strings.Split(tokenid, ".")
base64decode, err := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(testparse[1])
fmt.Println("Claims:", string(base64decode))
```

or better use "**github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go**" & "**github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk**" to do something like:

`jwt.Parse(yourTokenStr, getKeyFunction)`

then in your `getKeyFunction()` you can do:

```
fmt.Println("Header: Alg:", token.Header["alg"], ", Kid: ", token.Header["kid"])

claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)

// Print unverified claims
for key, value := range claims {
    log.Printf("%s\t: %v\n", key, value)
    if key == "iss" {
        // AWS cognito uses /.well-known/jwks.json path for the pub key
        jwksURL = value.(string) + "/.well-known/jwks.json"
    }
}
...
```

If your `jwt.Parse(yourTokenStr, getKeyFunction)` won't return any error the token is valid.

The errors you can get for example are "**Token is expired**" or (for my case) a more generic "**crypto/rsa: verification error**" if it is an expired Token_ID.

Comment: Thanks. I figured this out almost 3 years ago, but glad to see someone out there cares :)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a Json Web Token, You can verify them using any JWT library.

The token structure is explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html.

Read "Using ID Tokens and Access Tokens in your Web APIs" section at the link given above.

And seconfly, since it is a JWT, you do not need to call Cognito for every request. Just verify the the token.