# How to verify a JWT Token from AWS Cognito in Go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, jwt, amazon-cognito, jwt-go

How can I validate and get info from a JWT received from Amazon Cognito?

I have setup Google authentication in Cognito, and set the redirect uri to to hit API Gateway, I then receive a code which I POST to this endpoint:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

To receive the JWT token, in a RS256 format. I am now struggling to validate, and parse the token in Golang. I’ve tried to parse it using jwt-go, but it appears to support HMAC instead by default and read somewhere that they recommend using frontend validation instead. I tried a few other packages and had similar problems.

I came across this answer here: [Go Language and Verify JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077953/go-language-and-verify-jwt) but assume the code is outdated as that just says `panic: unable to find key`.

jwt.io can easily decode the key, and probably verify too. I’m not sure where the public/secret keys are as Amazon generated the token, but from what I understand I need to use a JWK URL to validate too? I’ve found a few AWS specific solutions, but they all seem to be hundreds of lines long. Surely it isn’t that complicated in Golang is it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Public keys for Amazon Cognito**

As you already guessed, you'll need the public key in order to verify the JWT token.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-step-2

> Download and store the corresponding public JSON Web Key (JWK) for your user pool. It is available as part of a JSON Web Key Set (JWKS).
> You can locate it at
> https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json

**Parse keys and verify token**

That JSON file structure is documented in the web, so you could potentially parse that manually, generate the public keys, etc.

But it'd probably be easier to just use a library, for example this one:
https://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx

And then jwt-go to deal with the JWT part: https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go

You can then:

1. Download and parse the public keys JSON using the first library

   ```
    keySet, err := jwk.Fetch(THE_COGNITO_URL_DESCRIBED_ABOVE)
   ```
2. When parsing the token with jwt-go, use the "kid" field from the JWT header to find the right key to use

   ```
    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRS256); !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
    }
    kid, ok := token.Header["kid"].(string)
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("kid header not found")
    }
    keys := keySet.LookupKeyID(kid);
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("key with specified kid is not present in jwks")
    }
    var publickey interface{}
    err = keys.Raw(&publickey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not parse pubkey")
    }
    return publickey, nil
   ```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore since Materialize has been renamed into Raw. Also Raw takes key type.

Comment: Starting from `lestrrat-go/jwx v1.x.y`): you can replace `return keys[0].Materialize()` by:
`var pubkey interface{}`, then `err := key[0].Raw(&pubkey)` and `return pubkey, nil`. Ensure you do an error check on the err (return value of the Raw method)

Answer (score 9):

This is what I did with only the latest (`v1.0.8`) `github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx`. Note that `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go` does not seem to be maintained anymore and people are forking it to make the updates they need.

```golang
package main

import (
    ...
    "github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk"
    "github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwt"
)
    ...

    keyset, err := jwk.Fetch("https://cognito-idp." + region + ".amazonaws.com/" + userPoolID + "/.well-known/jwks.json")

    parsedToken, err := jwt.Parse(
        bytes.NewReader(token), //token is a []byte
        jwt.WithKeySet(keyset),
        jwt.WithValidate(true),
        jwt.WithIssuer(...),
        jwt.WithClaimValue("key", value),
    )

    //check err as usual
    //here you can call methods on the parsedToken to get the claim values
    ...
```

[Token claim methods](https://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/blob/master/jwt/token_gen.go#L42)

Comment: Works for me; some notes: (1) The issuer in AWS must be: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<userpoolID>, (2) you should use WithClaimValue to validate "token_use" is "id" or "access" as per the previous link, (3) the first token param should be the raw base64-encoded ID token, last (4) if you are using a unit test to validate a real AWS ID token like I did you will fail validation due to expiration of the token if you do not use the WithClock(...) option.

Comment: Ah, one last note, you must also validate the audience, so use WithAudience. In AWS the audience is the client ID of the app client.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. The only thing you need to do is to update to `"github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/v2/jwk"
 "github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/v2/jwt"`

Answer (score 7):

The type assertion in the code provided by eugenioy and Kevin Wydler did not work for me: `*jwt.SigningMethodRS256 is not a type`.

`*jwt.SigningMethodRS256` was a type in the initial commit. From the second commit on (back in July 2014) it was abstracted and replaced by a global variable (see [here](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/commit/629af62465e3c5e2ab5c5e97d22d4e593ab0a9bc#diff-cc15cd66e8c9e3a7ca06b9a7dc9bdce7)).

This following code works for me:

```golang
func verify(tokenString string, keySet *jwk.Set) {
  tkn, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    if token.Method.Alg() != "RSA256" { // jwa.RS256.String() works as well
      return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
    }
    kid, ok := token.Header["kid"].(string)
    if !ok {
      return nil, errors.New("kid header not found")
    }
    keys := keySet.LookupKeyID(kid)
    if len(keys) == 0 {
      return nil, fmt.Errorf("key %v not found", kid)
    }
    var raw interface{}
    return raw, keys[0].Raw(&raw)
  })
}
```

Using the following dependency versions:

```
github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/v4 v4.0.0-preview1
github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx v1.0.4
```

Answer (score 5):

eugenioy's answer stopped working for me because of [this refactor](https://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/pull/169). I ended up fixing with something like this

```golang
token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRS256); !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
    }
    kid, ok := token.Header["kid"].(string)
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("kid header not found")
    }
    keys := keySet.LookupKeyID(kid);
    if len(keys) == 0 {
         return nil, fmt.Errorf("key %v not found", kid)
    }
    // keys[0].Materialize() doesn't exist anymore
    var raw interface{}
    return raw, keys[0].Raw(&raw)
})
```

Comment: This worked with the addition of the github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk package for the keySet.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [an example](https://github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc/blob/master/examples/aws_cognito/main.go) using `github.com/golang-jwt/jwt`, (formally known as `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`,) and a JWKs like the one AWS Cognito provides.

It'll refresh the AWS Cognito JWKs once every hour, refresh when a JWT signed with an unknown `kid` comes in, and have a global rate limit of 1 HTTP request to refresh the JWKs every 5 minutes.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4"

    "github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc"
)

func main() {
    // Get the JWKS URL from your AWS region and userPoolId.
    //
    // See the AWS docs here:
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html
    regionID := ""   // TODO Get the region ID for your AWS Cognito instance.
    userPoolID := "" // TODO Get the user pool ID of your AWS Cognito instance.
    jwksURL := fmt.Sprintf("https://cognito-idp.%s.amazonaws.com/%s/.well-known/jwks.json", regionID, userPoolID)

    // Create the keyfunc options. Use an error handler that logs. Refresh the JWKS when a JWT signed by an unknown KID
    // is found or at the specified interval. Rate limit these refreshes. Timeout the initial JWKS refresh request after
    // 10 seconds. This timeout is also used to create the initial context.Context for keyfunc.Get.
    options := keyfunc.Options{
        RefreshErrorHandler: func(err error) {
            log.Printf("There was an error with the jwt.Keyfunc\nError: %s", err.Error())
        },
        RefreshInterval:   time.Hour,
        RefreshRateLimit:  time.Minute * 5,
        RefreshTimeout:    time.Second * 10,
        RefreshUnknownKID: true,
    }

    // Create the JWKS from the resource at the given URL.
    jwks, err := keyfunc.Get(jwksURL, options)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create JWKS from resource at the given URL.\nError: %s", err.Error())
    }

    // Get a JWT to parse.
    jwtB64 := "eyJraWQiOiJmNTVkOWE0ZSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJLZXNoYSIsImF1ZCI6IlRhc2h1YW4iLCJpc3MiOiJqd2tzLXNlcnZpY2UuYXBwc3BvdC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2MTkwMjUyMTEsImlhdCI6MTYxOTAyNTE3NywianRpIjoiMWY3MTgwNzAtZTBiOC00OGNmLTlmMDItMGE1M2ZiZWNhYWQwIn0.vetsI8W0c4Z-bs2YCVcPb9HsBm1BrMhxTBSQto1koG_lV-2nHwksz8vMuk7J7Q1sMa7WUkXxgthqu9RGVgtGO2xor6Ub0WBhZfIlFeaRGd6ZZKiapb-ASNK7EyRIeX20htRf9MzFGwpWjtrS5NIGvn1a7_x9WcXU9hlnkXaAWBTUJ2H73UbjDdVtlKFZGWM5VGANY4VG7gSMaJqCIKMxRPn2jnYbvPIYz81sjjbd-sc2-ePRjso7Rk6s382YdOm-lDUDl2APE-gqkLWdOJcj68fc6EBIociradX_ADytj-JYEI6v0-zI-8jSckYIGTUF5wjamcDfF5qyKpjsmdrZJA"

    // Parse the JWT.
    token, err := jwt.Parse(jwtB64, jwks.Keyfunc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse the JWT.\nError: %s", err.Error())
    }

    // Check if the token is valid.
    if !token.Valid {
        log.Fatalf("The token is not valid.")
    }
    log.Println("The token is valid.")

    // End the background refresh goroutine when it's no longer needed.
    jwks.EndBackground()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A newer method to achieve verification and access the token is to use [Gin Cognito JWT Authentication Middleware](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/akhettar/gin-jwt-cognito):

```
package main

import (
    jwtCognito "github.com/akhettar/gin-jwt-cognito"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    
    // Create the authentication middleware
    mw, err := jwtCognito.AuthJWTMiddleware(<iss>, <user_pool_id>, <region>)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }   
  
    r.GET("/someGet", mw.MiddlewareFunc(), func(c *gin.Context) {
        // Get the token
        tokenStr, _ := c.Get("JWT_TOKEN")
        token := tokenStr.(*jwt.Token)

        // Cast the claims
        claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)

        log.Printf("userCognitoId=%v", claims["cognito:username"])
        log.Printf("userName=%v", claims["name"])
        
        c.Status(http.StatusOK)
    })

    // By default it serves on :8080
    r.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func verifyToken(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    // make sure to replace this with your actual URL
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-step-2
    jwksURL := "COGNITO_JWKS_URL" 
    set, err := jwk.FetchHTTP(jwksURL)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    keyID, ok := token.Header["kid"].(string)
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("expecting JWT header to have string kid")
    }

    keys := set.LookupKeyID(keyID)
    if len(keys) == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("key %v not found", keyID)
    }

    if key := set.LookupKeyID(keyID); len(key) == 1 {
        return key[0].Materialize()
    }

    return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to find key %q", keyID)
}
```

I am calling it like this (using AWS Lambda `gin`) in my case. If you are using a different way of managing requests, make sure to replace that with `http.Request` or any other framework that you might be using:

```
func JWTVerify() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        tokenString := c.GetHeader("AccessToken")
        _, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, verifyToken)
        if err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `go.mod`:

```
module MY_MODULE_NAME
go 1.12

require (
    github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go v1.20.0
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.36.0
    github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-go-api-proxy v0.9.0
    github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go v3.2.0+incompatible
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.6.3
    github.com/google/uuid v1.1.2
    github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx v0.9.2
    github.com/onsi/ginkgo v1.14.2 // indirect
    github.com/onsi/gomega v1.10.3 // indirect
    golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1 // indirect
)
```