# JWK from Amazon Cognito doesn't contain X5c field

Tags: go, authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to hook up my GO web server to Amazon Cognito for auth. I'm using the jwt-middleware from gorilla. I'm also following the guide from AuthO: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/golang/01-authorization

The guide creates a cert using the following:

```
    for k, _ := range jwks.Keys {
        if token.Header["kid"] == jwks.Keys[k].Kid {
            cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" + jwks.Keys[k].X5c[0] + "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
        }
    }
```

AWS says to get your JWKs file using *https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json*

I did that but my file is missing the X5c field. It looks like:

```
{
    "keys": [{
        "alg": "RS256",
        "e": "AQAB",
        "kid": "abcdefghijklmnopqrsexample=",
        "kty": "RSA",
        "n": "lsjhglskjhgslkjgh43lj5h34lkjh34lkjht3example",
        "use": "sig"
    }, {
        "alg":
        "RS256",
        "e": "AQAB",
        "kid": "fgjhlkhjlkhexample=",
        "kty": "RSA",
        "n": "sgjhlk6jp98ugp98up34hpexample",
        "use": "sig"
    }]
}
```

**How am I supposed to verify the signature of the token sent in through the Authorization header sent by the client using this file?**

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread out [How to verify a JWT Token from AWS Cognito in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905995/how-to-verify-a-jwt-token-from-aws-cognito-in-go)

JWT Middleware "github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware" used in your example is deeply rooted in how auth.com service handles JWT and may not fully apply to other providers and services.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the key to `PEM` format for use with any OpenSSL or crypto library. In javascript, I used the `jwk-to-pem` package for node.  Which never uses the `x5c` prop, it uses the `n` prop on the JWK, which contains the value for the RSA public key.